# Как удалять в цикле определенные элементы Dictionary?

Tags: c#, словари

Есть такой словарь:

> Dictionary<MyScript, Vector3>.KeyCollection keys = myDict.Keys;

В словае пары MyScript, Vector3.
В цикле из словаря я извлекаю MyScript, работаю с ним и по необходимости удаляю этот элемент словаря.
С удалнием проблема - не знаю, как удалить все элементы из словаря, НЕ ПРОПУСТИВ ни одного. Дело в том, что удаление происходит так:

```
foreach (MyScript est in keys) {
    ...
    if()
        myDict.Remove(est);
    }
}
```

На следующей итерации, ЕСЛИ ОБЬЕКТ i-й был удален, возьмется всё равно следующий, то есть i+1, но так как список сдвинулся после удаления, то возьмется i+2. Было бы хорошо, если бы можно было пройтись по списку примерно такого типа:

```
for (int i=0; i< keys.Count; ++i) {
        ...
        if(keys[i]== ???)
            myDict.Remove(keys[i]);
            --i;// <Сдвиг назад, так как элемент удален
        }
    }
```

Как можно удалить из Dictionary все MyScripts, у которых выполняется определенное условие?

Comment: так приведите ```var keysArray = keys.ToArray()``` и пользуйте ```for``` цикл

Answer (score 1):

Если вам важна скорость, можно перезаписывать нужные элементы в новый словарь, то есть :

```
Dictionnary<MyScript, Vector3> newDict = new Dictionnary<MyScript, Vector3>();

foreach(MyScript element in keys)
{
    DoSomething();

    if (!condition) //нужное условие не выполнилось
    {
         newDict.Add(element, myDict[element]);
    }
}
```

Тогда `newDict` будет словарем с нужными элементами, а `newDict.Keys` список с нужными ключами

Answer (score 0):

При первом проходе заносите выбранные ключи в коллекцию:

```
var keysForRemove = new List<...>();
foreach (MyScript est in keys)
{
    ...
    if()
        keysForRemove.Add(est);
    }
}
```

При повторном проходе удаляйте из словаря:

```
foreach (var key in keysForRemove)
    myDict.Remove(key);
```

Comment: Если писать: Dictionary<MyScript, Vector3>.KeyCollection keys = myDict.Keys; То получаю: error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<MyScript,UnityEngine.Vector3>.KeyCollection'

Comment: Прочитал первый раз вопрос не внимательно. Обновил ответ. @Alerr